# Debugging Unit tests with Atom (Vue application)

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, vue.js, atom-editor

Is there a way to debug, via breakpoints, unit tests on a VueJS project?

I currently have the default Vue CLI setup and am using the official Vue plugin for Mocha-Webpack, as configured by the CLI. I am trying to figure out how to connect any of the debugger packages in Atom with the cli command that runs our unit tests.

The desired outcome is that I can add a breakpoint within Atom IDE and run 'vue-cli-service test:unit' and have it stop at each breakpoint so we can properly debug out unit tests. A nice to have would also be the ability to run individual tests as well with the ability to debug with breakpoints.

I have searched and have not been able to find anything. Out tests are running as expected but being able to debug them would be a huge help. Thanks!